OAuth 2 - how to securely start an external browser from C#?
What is the best way to start an external browser from C# in order to initiate e.g. the OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow?
For example is the following secure enough:
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(<some url>);
What then if a malicious person has registered his own tool instead of a browser picking up entered credentials?

Basically, you don't.  All you can do is start 'the' browser with the url of the login page. If you want ,  you could start a specific browser by someone finding the correct executable for Firebox, Chrome, Edge etc.  If a malicious user has managed to install their own browser, it's unlikely to have access to the correct credentials, so you would then need the user to enter them, but at that point, they already have access to a lot of the local PC.

@Neil - So from your point of view it is acceptable (from a security point of view) just to start the browser as described? Based on the reason that if a malicious person already had access to the computer then he could have/can do whatever he wants?

https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/mobile-and-native-apps/authorization/

@Neil - meaning that the Process.Start approach is acceptable from a security point of view?

Highly influenced of how Azure behaves when issuing the following command:
az login
I think it is acceptable to run System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(<some url>); when initiating an OAuth2 authorization code flow.
Looking at the source code for Azure CLI it turns out that the method PublicClientApplication.acquire_token_interactive is invoked. PublicClientApplication is from the MSAL library. Eventually the Python webbrowser.open is invoked which simply evaluates to
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmdline)

This is no better than Process.start().
Also worth mentioning is that there is no connection between the popped up browser window and the az login command prompt in the sense that e.g. closing the browser window instead of doing the authorization will not make the az login continue with an OAuth2 failure - the command prompt will simply hang.

You can't with any degree of reasonable certainty. You can use that same function call and replace the url with the path to an executable. In this way you control what process is spun up, but the reference to that executable can be hijacked by a process with sufficient permissions via a sym-link to their malicious executable if they want. Is there a reason this has to be handled in the browser as opposed to handling the auth from the command line?

VirusModulePointer - My "starting point" is a GUI application and not a command prompt, and I want to perform the authorization code flow ending up with an access token from the authorization server.
